# ¿Por qué en la response me devuelve un array de objetos vacios cuando devuelvo un array lleno de structs?

Tags: go

estoy haciendo una restful y en uno de mis endpoint pero tengo unos inconvenientes que no veo, el array esta lleno con los structs pero a la hora de devolverlo con c.JSON, me devuelve el array con los objetos vacios, que podria ser?

```golang
[]models.CategoryExtendGroup{
    {
        category:   models.Category{ID:1, Name:"Instrumentos"},
        categories: {
            {IdCategory:1, IdSubcategory:1, Category:"Instrumentos", Subcategory:"Guitarras"},
            {IdCategory:1, IdSubcategory:2, Category:"Instrumentos", Subcategory:"Bajos"},
            {IdCategory:1, IdSubcategory:3, Category:"Instrumentos", Subcategory:"Baterías"},
            {IdCategory:1, IdSubcategory:4, Category:"Instrumentos", Subcategory:"Teclados"},
            {IdCategory:1, IdSubcategory:5, Category:"Instrumentos", Subcategory:"Equipo de voces"},
            {IdCategory:1, IdSubcategory:6, Category:"Instrumentos", Subcategory:"Amplificacion"},
            {IdCategory:1, IdSubcategory:7, Category:"Instrumentos", Subcategory:"Viento"},
            {IdCategory:1, IdSubcategory:8, Category:"Instrumentos", Subcategory:"Cuerda"},
            {IdCategory:1, IdSubcategory:9, Category:"Instrumentos", Subcategory:"Percusión"},
            {IdCategory:1, IdSubcategory:10, Category:"Instrumentos", Subcategory:"Accesorios"},
        },
    },

}
```

```golang
func CategoriesExtendGroupController(c *gin.Context) {
    u, err := models.GetCategoriesExtendGroup()

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    pretty.Print(u)
    c.JSON(200, u)
}
```

```golang
func GetCategoriesExtendGroup() (categories []CategoryExtendGroup, err error) {
    categoriesArray, err := GetCategoriesExtend()
    var unique []CategoryExtendGroup
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    for _, categoryRow := range categoriesArray {
        var exist bool = false
        subcategory := CategoryExtend{
            IdCategory:    categoryRow.IdCategory,
            IdSubcategory: categoryRow.IdSubcategory,
            Category:      categoryRow.Category,
            Subcategory:   categoryRow.Subcategory,
        }
        for i, categoryUnique := range unique {
            if categoryUnique.category.ID == categoryRow.IdCategory {
                exist = true
                unique[i].categories = append(unique[i].categories, subcategory)
                break
            }
        }
        if !exist {
            unique = append(unique, CategoryExtendGroup{
                category: models.Category{
                    ID:   categoryRow.IdCategory,
                    Name: categoryRow.Category,
                },
                categories: []CategoryExtend{subcategory},
            })
        }
    }
    categories = unique
    err = nil
    return
}
```

Estos son mis strucs:

```golang
type CategoryExtend struct {
    IdCategory    int64  `json:"id_category"`
    IdSubcategory int64  `json:"id_subcategory"`
    Category      string `json:"category"`
    Subcategory   string `json:"subcategory"`
}
type CategoryExtendGroup struct {
    category   models.Category
    categories []CategoryExtend
}
```

La cosa es que cuando miro el swagger me devuelve esto:

```
[
  {},
  {},
  {},
  {},
  {},
  {},
  {}
]
```

Y no entiendo porque me devuelve el objeto vacio si cuando hago el `pretty.Print(u)` veo todos los datos
Estoy usando el framework de go(gin-gonic)

Hace dos 1 mes empece con este lenguaje, empece con el porque necesitaba que fuera mas rapido

Muchas Gracias a tod@s
Saludos

Comment: No estoy seguro, pero las propiedades dentro del `CategoryExtendGroup`, están en minúsculas, lo que indica que son privadas dentro de ese `struct`, probablemente no se pueden acceder para ser enviadas en json

Comment: Tio eres un genio, ni lo he visto!!! Muchas gracias por tu ayuda!!! Ya estaba ofuscado

Comment: Ok, lo voy a dejar como respuesta ya que le puede servir a otras personas.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que sucede que dentro del `struct` `CategoryExtendGroup` las propiedades al estar en minúsculas son propiedades privadas inaccesibles por el método que convierte tu `struct` en `json`. Para solucionarlo solo has:

```
type CategoryExtendGroup struct {
    Category   models.Category
    Categories []CategoryExtend
}
```

Si ademas quieres conseguir que lo que se envié aparezca en minúscula, puede agregarle, al igual que con el struct `CategoryExtend` los tags `json:"category"`. Quedando de esta manera:

```
type CategoryExtendGroup struct {
    Category   models.Category `json:"category"`
    Categories []CategoryExtend `json:"categories"`
}
```